# Temporary link per user request in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a temporary link for every request that is sent in by a user.. This is based on a web server accessed via USSD by the public. IS it prudent to create a script that generates a temporary link for every user request or have a temporary link that expires after a period?

My aim is so as to limit each user to one single access to the resource and avoid multiple use of the same link.

Thanks

Comment: When you want resources to be accessible only by certain user's a certain amount of time, you have to hide it from your web_root and instead serve it through a PHP-script, which checks if a previously generated id was already accessed or not... Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a random token, save it somewhere. For example, in a database with a creation/expiration timestamp.
2. Give the user the link with the token, e.g.:

   ```
   example.com/resource.php?token=o3thpnof2039gjpogn3p0g
   ```
3. On `resource.php`, check if the token is present and valid. If it is, mark it as used/remove it and give the user what he wants. If not, throw up a 404 page.